# Remove the empty elements and segments in XSLT transformed xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml with empty elements and segments and I want to get rid of the empty elements and segments and have an output only with values.
Below is my input xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
   <Envelope>
      <Version>1.8</Version>
      <MessageType>ttyyuu</MessageType>
      <SenderID>55556677</SenderID>
      <ReceiverID>777778</ReceiverID>
      <TransactionID>667777</TransactionID>
   </Envelope>
   <Head>
      <PurchaseOrderNumber>6777888</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <PurchaseOrderDate>2021-03-17</PurchaseOrderDate>
      <IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>true</IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>
      <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
      <IncoTermsISOCode>uuuu</IncoTermsISOCode>
      <OrderType>ttyyy</OrderType>
      <ShipmentTypeCode>3</ShipmentTypeCode>
      <ThirdPartyCustomerData>
         <SalesOrganization/>
         <SpecialProcessingIndicator/>
         <StoreNumber/>
         <Email/>
         <CustomerAddress>
            <Name/>
            <Street/>
            <ZipCode/>
            <City/>
            <CountryCode/>
         </CustomerAddress>
      </ThirdPartyCustomerData>
      <Addresses>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>yyyuuu</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>456788</AddressCode>
            <Name/>
            <Street/>
            <ZipCode/>
            <City/>
            <CountryCode/>
            <MobilePhoneNumber/>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttyy</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>567788</AddressCode>
            <Name/>
            <Street/>
            <ZipCode/>
            <City/>
            <CountryCode/>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>6577888</MobilePhoneNumber>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttt</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>7350019560006</AddressCode>
            <Name/>
            <Street/>
            <ZipCode/>
            <City/>
            <CountryCode/>
            <MobilePhoneNumber/>
         </Address>
      </Addresses>
   </Head>
   <Rows>
      <Row>
         <PurchaseOrderRowNumber>77788</PurchaseOrderRowNumber>
         <WebOrder/>
         <SalesOrder/>
         <SalesOrderLine/>
         <RequestedDeliveryDate>2021-09-06</RequestedDeliveryDate>
         <ActionCode/>
         <RowFreeTexts>
            <RowFreeText>
               <TextId/>
               <FreeText/>
            </RowFreeText>
         </RowFreeTexts>
      </Row>
   </Rows>
</Order>
```

I have tried the below xslt which is able to do most of the part but one segment  is still present after the transformation.
xslt:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(node())]
  |
   *[not(node()[2])
   and
     node()/self::text()
   and
     not(normalize-space())
     ]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:-

```
<Order>
   <Envelope>
      <Version>1.8</Version>
      <MessageType>ttyyuu</MessageType>
      <SenderID>55556677</SenderID>
      <ReceiverID>777778</ReceiverID>
      <TransactionID>667777</TransactionID>
   </Envelope>
   <Head>
      <PurchaseOrderNumber>6777888</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <PurchaseOrderDate>2021-03-17</PurchaseOrderDate>
      <IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>true</IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>
      <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
      <IncoTermsISOCode>uuuu</IncoTermsISOCode>
      <OrderType>ttyyy</OrderType>
      <ShipmentTypeCode>3</ShipmentTypeCode>
      <ThirdPartyCustomerData>
         <CustomerAddress/>
      </ThirdPartyCustomerData>
      <Addresses>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>yyyuuu</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>456788</AddressCode>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttyy</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>567788</AddressCode>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>6577888</MobilePhoneNumber>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttt</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>7350019560006</AddressCode>
         </Address>
      </Addresses>
   </Head>
   <Rows>
      <Row>
         <PurchaseOrderRowNumber>77788</PurchaseOrderRowNumber>
         <RequestedDeliveryDate>2021-09-06</RequestedDeliveryDate>
         <RowFreeTexts>
            <RowFreeText/>
         </RowFreeTexts>
      </Row>
   </Rows>
</Order>
```

Expected Output:-

```
<Order>
   <Envelope>
      <Version>1.8</Version>
      <MessageType>ttyyuu</MessageType>
      <SenderID>55556677</SenderID>
      <ReceiverID>777778</ReceiverID>
      <TransactionID>667777</TransactionID>
   </Envelope>
   <Head>
      <PurchaseOrderNumber>6777888</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <PurchaseOrderDate>2021-03-17</PurchaseOrderDate>
      <IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>true</IsPartialDeliveryAllowed>
      <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
      <IncoTermsISOCode>uuuu</IncoTermsISOCode>
      <OrderType>ttyyy</OrderType>
      <ShipmentTypeCode>3</ShipmentTypeCode>
      <Addresses>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>yyyuuu</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>456788</AddressCode>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttyy</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>567788</AddressCode>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>6577888</MobilePhoneNumber>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <AddressType>rrttt</AddressType>
            <AddressCode>7350019560006</AddressCode>
         </Address>
      </Addresses>
   </Head>
   <Rows>
      <Row>
         <PurchaseOrderRowNumber>77788</PurchaseOrderRowNumber>
         <RequestedDeliveryDate>2021-09-06</RequestedDeliveryDate>
         <RowFreeTexts>
            <RowFreeText/>
         </RowFreeTexts>
      </Row>
   </Rows>
</Order>
```

Comment: Why is `<RowFreeTexts> ...` included in the expected output?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k,
<Row> is a mandatory segment and it needs to have <RowFreeTexts> even if its empty.
but that is not the case for <ThirdPartyCustomerData>. so, downstream system does not want it if its empty.

Comment: How could anyone tell this from reading your question??

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k,
Yes, I should have been clearer about the above point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `RowFreeTexts/RowFreeText` should be excluded from the general rule,

then you maybe need this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[normalize-space()='']"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="RowFreeTexts|RowFreeText" priority="2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Compact XSLT 3 approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can run XSLT 3 using Saxon (open-source HE) 10 on Java or .NET or C/C++/Python or Saxon-JS 2 in the browser or with Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(string())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove all branches of the input XML tree that do not contain any text nodes. Thus the result is different from the expected output shown in your question.

Another way to express the same thing would be:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text())]"/>
```

Note that this does not check for the existence of attributes.

---

***-- added ---***

> `<Row>` is a mandatory segment and it needs to have `<RowFreeTexts>` even if its empty.

If you want to exclude `RowFreeTexts` and its descendants from being removed when empty, then simply change it to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(ancestor-or-self::RowFreeTexts)][not(string())]"/>
```